# Is there a way to not align my code when formatting with floskell?

Tags: haskell, formatter

I changed every indent to "indent-by n" and every align to false but floskell still seem to be aligning my code. I also tried modifying penalty configuration but the documentation is to minimal for me to make it work. Is it possible to let floskell not align my code at all?

If not, is there an alternative configurable formatter for haskell?

This is my floskell.json

```json
{
  "formatting": {
    "align": {
      "case": false,
      "class": false,
      "import-module": false,
      "import-spec": false,
      "let-binds": false,
      "matches": false,
      "record-fieds": false,
      "where": false
    },
    "group": {
      "(": {
        "force-linebreak": false,
        "linebreaks": "after",
        "spaces": "none"
      },
      "( in other": {
        "force-linebreak": true,
        "linebreaks": "after",
        "spaces": "both"
      },
      "[": {
        "force-linebreak": true,
        "linebreaks": "after",
        "spaces": "both"
      },
      "[ in pattern": {
        "force-linebreak": false,
        "linebreaks": "after",
        "spaces": "none"
      },
      "[ in type": {
        "force-linebreak": false,
        "linebreaks": "after",
        "spaces": "none"
      }
    },
    "indent": {
      "case": "indent-by 2",
      "class": "indent-by 2",
      "deriving": 2,
      "do": "indent-by 2",
      "export-spec-list": "indent-by 2",
      "if": "indent-by 2",
      "import-spec-list": "indent-by 2",
      "let": "indent-by 2",
      "let-binds": "indent-by 2",
      "let-in": "indent-by 2",
      "multi-if": "indent-by 2",
      "onside": 2,
      "typesig": "indent-by 2",
      "where": 2,
      "where-binds": "indent-by 2"
    },
    "layout": {
      "app": "flex",
      "con-decls": "try-oneline",
      "declaration": "try-oneline",
      "export-sepc-list": "flex",
      "if": "try-oneline",
      "import-spec-list": "flex",
      "infix-app": "try-oneline",
      "let": "try-oneline",
      "list-comp": "try-oneline",
      "record": "try-oneline",
      "type": "try-oneline"
    },
    "op": {
      "-> in expression": {
        "force-linebreak": false,
        "linebreaks": "after",
        "spaces": "both"
      },
      ",": {
        "force-linebreak": false,
        "linebreaks": "before",
        "spaces": "after"
      },
      "= in other": {
        "force-linebreak": false,
        "linebreaks": "before",
        "spaces": "both"
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "align-sum-type-decl": false,
      "flexible-oneline": true,
      "preserve-vertical-space": true,
      "sort-import-lists": true,
      "sort-imports": [
        {
          "order": "sorted",
          "prefixes": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      ],
      "sort-pragmas": true,
      "split-language-pragmas": true
    }
  },
  "style": "base"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `layout.app` to `"try-oneline"` helped.

Credit to [u/ennocramer](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ilcyau/is_there_a_way_to_not_align_my_code_when/g3ycn0m)